# TCP `net.Conn.Read` hangs following use of an `encoding/gob` decoder

Tags: go, tcp, network-programming, deadlock, gob

I can wrap ends of a TCP `net.Conn` with an `encoding/gob` en/decoder and en/decode a value through it successfully, but if I follow the `Decode` with a `Read` on the raw connection it hangs on the `Read`:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/gob"
    "net"
    "log"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    addr := &net.TCPAddr{IP: net.ParseIP("127.0.0.1"), Port: 9000}
    ready := make(chan struct{})

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()

        ln, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp4", addr)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("ln: ", err)
        }
        defer ln.Close()

        close(ready)

        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("conn: ", err)
        }
        defer conn.Close()

        var out string
        if err := gob.NewDecoder(conn).Decode(&out); err != nil {
            log.Fatal("error decoding: ", err)
        }
        if "hello" != out {
            log.Fatalf("1 expected '%s', got '%s'", "hello", out)
        }

        b := make([]byte, 1)
        log.Println("ready to read 1")
        if _, err := conn.Read(b); err != nil {
            log.Fatal("error reading: ", err)
        }
        log.Println("read 1")
        if b[0] != 1 {
            log.Fatalf("2 expected '%d', got '%d'", 1, b[0])
        }

        if _, err := conn.Write([]byte{1}); err != nil {
            log.Fatal("err writing2: ", err)
        }
        log.Println("done 1")
    }()

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()

        <-ready

        conn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp4", nil, addr)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("conn2: ", err)
        }
        defer conn.Close()

        if err := gob.NewEncoder(conn).Encode("hello"); err != nil {
            log.Fatal("error encoding: ", err)
        }

        if _, err := conn.Write([]byte{1}); err != nil {
            log.Fatal("write error: ", err)
        }

        b := make([]byte, 1)
        log.Println("ready to read 2")
        if _, err := conn.Read(b); err != nil {
            log.Fatal("error reading2: ", err)
        }
        log.Println("read 2")
        if b[0] != 1 {
            log.Fatalf("3 expected '%d', got '%d'", 1, b[0])
        }
        log.Println("done 2")
    }()

    log.Println("waiting")
    wg.Wait()
    log.Println("waited")
}
```

The output:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 waiting
2009/11/10 23:00:00 ready to read 2
2009/11/10 23:00:00 ready to read 1
```

This causes a [deadlock panic](https://play.golang.org/p/xH9Cxm0pXG) in the Go Playground and hangs on my local machine (`go version go1.6.2 darwin/amd64`), though intermittently the code will execute to completion locally.

This doesn't happen if I use a `net.PipeConn` or if I follow the `Decode` with a `Write` instead (i.e. swap the order of the `Read`/`Write` following the en/decode). The code following the en/decode also works in isolation when I remove the en/decode code.

What is causing this hang? This feels like a caching issue but I don't know why the `Write` wouldn't flush or why the `Read` wouldn't pull the latest available data, or why this issue only appears when `gob` en/decoding is involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gob` wraps the reader in a [`bufio.Reader`](https://golang.org/src/encoding/gob/decoder.go?s=1473:1510#L41) if the reader isn't already a bufio, you really have 2 options:

1. Wrap your conn in a bufio.Reader and pass that to gob and use it from that point on.
2. Use gob for everything and don't manually read/write.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand, in lower-level terms the buffer likely read the extra byte that I sent? Thanks very much for the answer!